# Identify animated TV series having Silver Surfer

Tags: story-identification, tv, silver-surfer

I once used to watch an animated TV series (having Silver Surfer) which I have almost forgotten. Here are some blurred visuals in my mind:

- The villain's ship was of a monster face shaped which travelled smashing asteroids from face side.
- I am not 100% sure, but the villain was Galactus. And, Silver Surfer probably worked for him.
- Once Silver Surfer was enslaved on a planet with a band in his neck. Whenever he tried to break the band, electric shock neutralized him.

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems rude, but how were you having trouble finding this knowing that it was a Silver Surfer cartoon?

Comment: @KevinHowell To be fair, I believe he shows up in a few animated shows of the same era. But, yes, if you just look up "Silver Surfer animated series", it's the first hit.

Comment: @KevinHowell Sorry, I phrased it wrong way. I couldn't tell whether the cartoon was around Silver Surfer as he worked for a villain. Correcting..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was the [Silver Surfer Animated Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer_(TV_series)) from 1998.

> - The villain's ship was of a monster face shaped which travelled smashing asteroids from face side.

Thanos' ship is shaped like a face, and travels through asteroids. (clip is a bit grainy, but you can make it out).

> - I am not 100% sure, but the villain was Galactus. And, Silver Surfer probably worked for him.

Silver Surfer worked as the herald for Galactus.

> - Once Silver Surfer was enslaved on a planet with a band in his neck. Whenever he tried to break the band, electric shock neutralized him.

In episode four,  Silver Surfer is enslaved and has a collar fitted around his neck which would shock him.

Comment: And they adapted a [Harlan Ellison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlan_Ellison) story for an episode of the series!

Comment: Links are dead :/